# How to approach expectation of order statistic conditioned on known minimum?

Tags: conditional-expectation, order-statistics, exponential-family

Say you have an $n \times n$ matrix whose entries follow a standard exponential distribution, $A_{i,j} \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ for $1 \le i,j \le n$. You find the minimum value, $x_{i:n^2}$, and remove the corresponding row and column to produce an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix $A^\prime$ where every entry is $\ge x_{i:n^2}$.

I know the expected value of $X_{r:n^2}$ for this model is given by

$$\mathbb{E}\left(X_{r:n^2}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \frac{1}{n^2-i+1}$$

Hence, the expected minimum of $A$ is given by $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{1:n^2}\right) = 1/n^2$, but I'm having a hard time formulating what the expected minimum of $A^\prime$ will be. I know through numerical simulations that it is not just $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{1:(n-1)^2}\right)$.

I am most interested in the thinking of how to approach this problem, and far less about the actual solution. What approaches or techniques would be appropriate to use for this problem?

Comment: I think you ought to be able to do it with a messy numerical integration. Or just use simulation.  Do you need a closed-form solution?  if so, your only solution might be to define a new "closed-form" function, and then numerically evaluate it by one of the preceding approaches. On the other hand, maybe someone's clever enough to work it out for exponential distribution, which has magical properties.

Comment: My preference is to find a closed form solution that is needed by other parts of my work. I know there are closed form solutions for which $A_{i,j} \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ in the literature, so I'd like to believe there are closed form solutions for the exponential case since, as you point out, it has nice properties like memorylessness.

Comment: Did you look at the derivations for the U(0,1) case?